# How to receive email notification using IFTTT on React app and ThingHttp?

Tags: rest, email

I have followed this link below to configure my own React App using IFTTT and ThingHttp, the unfortunate part i want to receive an email notification. Currently my channels only show last Ran on all React App and non of email notification are sent to me. What could be an issue to my configuration and stuck now?

https://www.elecfreaks.com/store/blog/how-to-send-temperature-threshold-value-alarm-email-via-ifttt.html

[image: Table]

Answer (score 0):

I made some relook and found out that problem was on my side. Meaning the naming conversion was on the lower case instead of Upper Case. E.g temp_critical(name of my webhook and reactapp) instead of Temp_Critical(name of my webhook and email/reactapp, thinghttp). I was able to get an notification if my temperature was critical.